# Get list of files whose creation date is greater than some date linux

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, awk

I have these files in *Hadoop* and want the list of all files whose creation date is greater than `2016-11-21`.

```
-rw-r-----   3 pharpan1 hadoop      73439 2017-01-02 15:20 manpoc_pre
-rw-r-----   3 pharpan1 hadoop      12190 2017-02-02 19:42 message.txt
-rw-r-----   3 pharpan1 hadoop        374 2016-11-14 18:18 newbin
-rw-r-----   3 pharpan1 hadoop        614 2016-11-14 18:19 newcalcpi
-rw-r-----   3 pharpan1 hadoop        154 2016-11-21 20:12 newspoc
```

I tried the command below but it's printing all the files. How to get only the one's which satisfy the condition

```
 dateA='2016-11-21'
 hdfs dfs -ls -t | awk '{if($6 -ge dateA) print $8;}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the input date as a variable into `awk` expression(via `-v` option):

```
dateA='2016-11-21'
hdfs dfs -ls -t | awk -v dateA="$dateA" '{if ($6 > dateA) {print $8}}'
```

The output:

```
manpoc_pre
message.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

First, determine the number of days between now and 2016-11-21:

```
$ (( DAYS = ($(date +"%s") - $(date +"%s" -d "2016-11-21")) / ( 24 * 3600 ) ))
$ echo $DAYS
108
```

Next, use that variable to find the files:

```
find /my/directory -ctime -${DAYS} -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

filtering all the files created for a given date

```
hadoop fs -ls <path> | grep <filter_date> | sort
```